# Request theorem/Proof for $F(x)>0$ for $a<x<b$

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose 
$$
F(a)=0, F(b)=0, a<b
$$
and
$F''(x)<0$ for $a<x<b$.

Do we have $F(x) > 0$ for $a<x<b$?

Can you tell me an existing theorem that I can use in a paper to obtain the conclusion? I think there should be one, but I can't remember.

Comment: If $F(x) < 0$ for some $a < x < b$, then you can use the mean value theorem three times to show that $F''(X) > 0$ somewhere.

Comment: @arkeet I mean, can you tell me an existing theorem that I can use in a paper to obtain the conclusion? I think there should be one, but I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the [convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of $-F(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

Suppose $F(c) < 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$.    By the mean value theorem, there exist values $d_1 \in (a,c)$ and $d_2 \in (c,b)$ such that 
\begin{align}
F'(d_1) = \frac{F(c) - F(a)}{c - a} = \frac{F(c)}{b-a} < 0
\\
~
\\
F'(d_2) = \frac{F(b) - F(c)}{b - c} = \frac{-F(c)}{c-b}> 0,
\end{align}
and hence $F'(x)$ changes sign somewhere on $(a,b)$.  This contradicts $F''(x) < 0$.  Hence, $F(c) \geq 0$ for all $c \in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not. can be concave/not and positive between any two points. the concavity of the curve may also be changing at x. Depends on the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no theorem that I know of that talks specifically about this case, but you can prove it using a bit of simple calculus.

How about this proof: By Rolle's theorem, $F'(x) = 0$ at least once in the interval $(a, b)$. However it must happen exactly once since $F''(x) < 0$... This critical point is a maximum point, so we have $F(x)$ ascending from $(a, 0)$ towards a maximum and then descending back to $(b, 0)$.